# REACT- Fill checkbox if value=1 else not filled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, checkbox, react-hooks

how can I create a checkbox that is fill when item.availability=1 (for example) elif 0 it's not filled. I can return `{item.availability}` in `Checkbox` function but I want something more generique.

```
export default function Display() {
  ...      
  function Checkbox({ value }) {
    const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(true);

    return (
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          defaultChecked={checked}
          onChange={() => setChecked(!checked)}
        />
        {value}
      </label>
    );
  }
  return (
    <>
          ....
          {"Availability "}
          <Checkbox ({item[0].availability})/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just set the received value prop as initial state of the **checked** state. Then make the checked prop in the input element depending on the state:

```
function Checkbox({ value }) {
    const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(value);

    return (
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={checked}
          onChange={() => setChecked(checked => !checked)}
        />
        {value}
      </label>
    );
  }
```

Make sure to pass the prop correctly:

```
<Checkbox value={!!item.availability} />
```